# i want to darkest point in a image by accessing each coordinate

Tags: matlab, image-processing

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v52BC.png)

Here is the image ,in which find number of darkest point near the  circle.one method i was thinking is that we can find darkest point in 0-90 degree then 90-180 degree so that we can get all the dark point

Comment: Great, now what have you tried so far?

Comment: till now i know only logic how to do it.because i m new matlab i m not able to impelement it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the darkest points, then use a thresholding.

However, if you want to find the darkest areas with a minimum size, you can first perform a [closing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closing_(morphology)), then you apply the thresholding.

Comment: It's Erosion(Dilation(I)), with I your image, and dilation/erosion being the two main methods of mathematical morphology. I just add a link.